# IndexError: image index out of range usando PIL

Tags: python-2.7, processamento-de-imagens

Estou começando a trabalhar com processamento de imagens e preciso fazer um exercício simples de dobrar o tamanho de uma.

Possuo o seguinte script:

```
from PIL import Image

imagem = Image.open("local_da_Imagem", "r")

largura, altura = imagem.size

fator = 2

W = largura
H = altura

nova_largura = int(largura*fator)
nova_altura = int(altura*fator)

nova_imagem = Image.new("RGB", (nova_largura, nova_altura))

for col in range(nova_largura):
  for row in range(nova_altura):
      p = imagem.getpixel((col, row))
      nova_imagem.putpixel((col*fator, row*fator), 100)

nova_imagem.show()
```

Porém quando executo esse script, me retorna o erro: IndexError: image index out of range.

Alguém poderia me ajudar. Me mostrando onde estou errando nesse script?

Já agradeço aos que puderem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Os dois for estão sendo percoridos por nova_altura e nova_largura, que são a altura e largura original multiplicada por 2, e você está usando getPixel para pegar o pixel da imagem na posição. Ou seja, você está percorendo a imagem 2x o tamanho dela, pois percorre ela com os valores multiplicados por 2. Fora que você está passando no putPixel o valor 100, e não o valor retornado pelo getPixel. E de acordo com o algoritmo que você me passou que o 0x0 ficaria em 0x1, 1x0, 1x1.

Cheguei em algo assim:

```
from PIL import Image

imagem = Image.open("Downloads/rgb.png", "r")

largura, altura = imagem.size

fator = 2

W = largura
H = altura

nova_largura = int(largura*fator)
nova_altura = int(altura*fator)

nova_imagem = Image.new("RGB", (nova_largura, nova_altura))

for col in range(largura):
  for row in range(altura):
      p = imagem.getpixel((col, row))
      nova_imagem.putpixel((col*fator, row*fator), p)
      nova_imagem.putpixel((col*fator+1, row*fator+1), p)
      nova_imagem.putpixel((col*fator+1, row*fator), p)
      nova_imagem.putpixel((col*fator, row*fator+1), p)


nova_imagem.show()
```

Comment: Seria possível um exemplo de código corrigindo esse erro?

Comment: @Danilo Ai eu já não posso te ajudar, porque não sei como funciona o algoritmo, por exemplo, o pixel 0x0 iria ser copiado pra onde? 0x1? 1x0? 1x1? Ele ficaria no 0x0 também, mas teria que ser copiado em algum outro lugar pra imagem aumentar de tamanho.

Comment: OK. Sem problemas. Mas respondendo sua pergunta. Por exemplo, digamos que o valor RGB da minha imagem original na posicao 0x0 seja 1. Para dobrar minha imagem, eu tenho que copiar esse valor 1 para as seguintes posições da nova imagem (0x0, 0x1, 1x0, 1x1).

Comment: @Danilo editei e coloquei um código, não sei se está totalmente certo pq não testei muito, mas aparenta apresentar certo.

Comment: Muito Obrigado @Vinicius Macelai. Está funcionando sim!
Muito Obrigado mesmo.